# Cannot get element by text using Selenium and xPath

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, intellij-idea

I implemented the following line of code in Java. I am using Selenium and I am trying to get a web element by its text. As far as I know, this is not possible using css selectors.

What I have tried:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
            By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'element_945')]//span[contains(text(),'Test')]"))
```

What I wanna do with the code above: get that `span` element that contains the text "Test" and is somewhere within the element `div` whose class contains "element_945".
The `span` is not a direct child of `div` but is somewhere inside of it.
When I run the code above in the Chrome console, it gives me the right element.
When I run it from my code, it gives me `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //div[contains(@class,'element_945')]//span[contains(text(),'Test')] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)`

Thanks

Comment: Can you share exact `HTML` code that contains `<div class="element_945">...<span>Test...</span>...</div>`

Comment: @Andersson wow your comment actually made me realize where I went wrong! Basically the page is a job and it is rendered dynamically, so for each job that element's class is changed. I was checking one job in the code and another in the console.

Comment: So you solved your issue?

Comment: @Andersson yep!

Comment: @Codemon in that case, please either provide an answer yourself or close the question. If you provide an answer, then other people can learn from your mistake :)